# Find last edited date of file (strange exec behaviour)

Tags: find, stat

I am trying to get the last modified dates of all the word documents in all the directories below this one

```
$ pwd
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=myServer,share=myResources
```

If I do a regular find it returns exactly what I'd expect.

```
$ find . -name "*.do*"
> ./AnsettGoldenWing/Project Sheets/Ansett Golden Wing Text.doc
> ./B000114/Text/060913__B000114.doc
> ./B000170/B000170_projectdetails.doc
> ./B000208/Text Files/archive/060913__B000208.doc
```

But if I add the `-exec` that formats the results it all goes to pot.

```
$ find . -name "*.do*" -exec sh -c "stat --printf='%n --- %y \n' {}" \; > fileInfo.txt
> stat: cannot stat ‘./AnsettGoldenWing/Project’: No such file or directory
> stat: cannot stat ‘Sheets/Ansett’: No such file or directory
> stat: cannot stat ‘Golden’: No such file or directory
> stat: cannot stat ‘Wing’: No such file or directory
> stat: cannot stat ‘Text.doc’: No such file or directory
> stat: cannot stat ‘./B000208/Text’: No such file or directory
> sh: 1: Spa: not found
> stat: cannot stat ‘./B000503/Submission/Hyatt’: No such file or directory
```

How do I make it output:

```
> ./AnsettGoldenWing/Project Sheets/Ansett Golden Wing Text.doc --- date
> ./B000114/Text/060913__B000114.doc --- date
> ./B000170/B000170_projectdetails.doc --- date
> ./B000208/Text Files/archive/060913__B000208.doc --- date
```

I'm fairly new to the command line and this is the first time I've used an `-exec` with a `find` so it still feels like black magic to me.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the whitespaces in your file name. Your new shell doesn't treat it as literal and interpreting it as separated files.

You can using `-print0` option with `xargs` command:

```
find . -name "*.do*" -print0 | xargs -0 stat --printf='%n --- %y \n'
```

or using `-exec` command with `+` instead of `\;`:

```
find . -name "*.do*" -exec stat --printf='%n --- %y \n' {} +
```

Generally, you should avoid calling new shell, because you can not guarantee that your result (file name in this case) is interpreted safety by new shell.

Answer (score 2):

You need quoting for protecting the whitespace:

```
find . -name "*.do*" -exec sh -c "stat --printf='%n --- %y \n' '{}'" \;
```